# How to use a vue-concurrency Task Creator that accepts an argument?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I have a Vue 3 / TypeScript app using the [vue-concurrency](https://vue-concurrency.netlify.app/) library.

I almost have it working, but setting up a Task Creator to accept arguments is tricky.

For example, I have followed the [Task Creators pattern from the docs](https://vue-concurrency.netlify.app/composing-tasks/#task-creators) like so:

**`src/composables/tasks.ts`**

```TypeScript
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-call */
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-return */
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment */
import { timeout, useTask } from 'vue-concurrency';

export const useReturnTextTask = (text: string) => {
  return useTask(function* () {
    // Simulate an API call that takes a string argument and returns a string
    yield timeout(1000);
    return text;
  });
};
```

And I am using it inside a component like so:

**`src/components/example.vue`**

```vue
<template>
  <input v-model="textInput" type="text" />
  <button @click="handleClick">Click to Perform Task</button>
  <div v-if="returnTextTask.last?.isError">
    {{ returnTextTask.last?.error.message }}
  </div>
  <div v-else>
    {{ returnTextTask.last?.value }}
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access */
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment */
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-call */
import { useReturnTextTask } from 'src/composables/test';
import { ref } from 'vue';

const textInput = ref<string>();

const handleClick = async () => {
  if (textInput.value) {
    const returnTextTask = useReturnTextTask(textInput.value);
    const returnTextInstance = returnTextTask.perform();
    await returnTextInstance;
    if (returnTextTask.last?.isSuccessful) {
      console.log(returnTextTask.last?.value);
      console.log(returnTextInstance.value);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Now a problem arises because `useReturnTextTask` has a required `text` arugment, so I am using it inside `if (textInput.value)`.

But doing that causes all `returnTextTask` references in the template to have the error `Cannot find name 'returnTextTask'. ts(2304)`.

I assume this is because `returnTextTask` is not always defined when wrapped by `if (textInput.value)`.

How do I overcome this?

I have also tried using declaring `returnTextTask` outside `handleClick` using something like `let returnTextTask: Task<string, []>;` but that causes runtime errors because it's declared with an undefined value (`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'last')`).

Answer (score 0):

Ok so this was fixed by passing in refs and checking for undefined inside the Task generator, like so:

```
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-call */
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-return */
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment */
import { Ref } from 'vue';
import { timeout, useTask } from 'vue-concurrency';

export const useReturnTextTask = (text: Ref<string | undefined>) => {
  return useTask(function* () {
    if (text.value) {
      console.log('inside Task', text);
      yield timeout(1000);
      return text;
    } else {
      throw new Error('Text required.');
    }
  });
};
```

And moving the `useReturnTextTask()` to the top level like so:

```
<template>
  <input v-model="textInput" type="text" />
  <button @click="handleClick">Click to Perform Task</button>
  <div v-if="returnTextTask.last?.isError">
    {{ returnTextTask.last?.error.message }}
  </div>
  <div v-else>
    {{ returnTextTask.last?.value }}
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access */
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment */
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-call */
import { useReturnTextTask } from 'src/composables/test';
import { ref } from 'vue';

const textInput = ref<string>();

const returnTextTask = useReturnTextTask(textInput);

const handleClick = async () => {
  const returnTextInstance = returnTextTask.perform();
  await returnTextInstance;
  if (returnTextTask.last?.isSuccessful) {
    console.log('returnTextTask.last?.value', returnTextTask.last?.value);
    console.log('returnTextInstance.value', returnTextInstance.value);
  }
};
</script>
```